# When to call subprocess.communicate()?

Tags: python

I run a process and read the first line from `stderr` and check exit code:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['time', '-p', 'ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(p.stderr.readline().decode('utf-8'))
streamdata = p.communicate()[0]
print(f'exitcode: {p.returncode}')
```

is this code correct? Do I call `p.communicate()` in a right place?

Comment: I would guess it's not - but since you don't explain what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to be sure. Reading a single line via `stderr` seems wrong, since you can no longer access the whole output after that (given that the streams aren't seekable). A better approach would be add the `text=True` option to `Popen` and then simply do `out, err = p.communicate()`. If you specifically want the first line of `stderr`, you can then do `err.readlines()[0]`. (PS: see also the [warning in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout) regarding stdout etc).

Comment: PPS: you should probably also read the python docs for [Popen.communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) so as to fully understand how it operates.

Comment: @ekhumoro I am trying to read the first line without reading other ones and get exit code.

Comment: Then use `p.wait()` instead of `p.communicate()` (which will wait anyway). The docs are pretty informative. There are lots of options.

Comment: @ekhumoro another question is that what if I call `readline()` and then `wait()`, but there is no output at all before the process ends.

Comment: Nothing, I suppose - it will just print an empty string.